# Highcharts (Highcharts-Vue) Drilldown with Geojson Geometry Based Maps Fails To Display

Tags: dictionary, highcharts, drilldown

I've implemented the http://jsfiddle.net/maxsinev/h9x3kpn5/3/ method with Highcharts-Vue but my map (loaded from the Highcharts collection with a `import stateMap from '@highcharts/map-collection/countries/us/us-all.geo.json'` statement) has all the state shapes as Geometry elements rather than Path.

Also, if I load the series data from the statemap features, Highcharts won't look in properties; I have to modify properties to include drilldown = true and value = # then the return that from my features.map() call.

At this point, I am not sure if this is an issue with the Highcharts-Vue wrapper, the map I am loading, or if there is some setting to the chart itself that would help. I had to set chartOptions.chart.map to the stateMap as well (which the above cited example didn't do) otherwise no map shows.

Comment: Could you explain what you meant by 'has all the state shapes as Geometry elements rather than Path.'? I do not quite understand the problem you have, so could you describe it in more details? It might be much convenient to discuss it on support@highcharts.com, because of possible complexity of this thread, don't you?

Comment: If I add 

  mounted() {
    console.log(this.options.series[0].data);
  },

to the linked fiddle, each elements starts with { drilldown: true, name: <state name>, path: <path>, ... }. Path is a format I am not familiar with but appears to be a simplified representation of map coordinates projected flat to screen real estate.

However, when I load my map with:

import usMap from '@highcharts/map-collection/countries/us/us-all.geo.json';

and console.log(usMap), my elements have a geometry lat/lon coordinates rather than a path elements.

Answer (score 1):

TBH, I don't have the solution but I think I know why the drilldown functionality isn't working.

I am using the Highcharts-Vue wrapper which does a nice job of making Highcharts play nice in the Vue ecosystem but doesn't expose the function calls of the underlying objects. As such, if you want to make the map redraw, for instance, one has to go through $refs to get to the underlying object and then call redraw something like:

```
<highcharts :options="chartOptions" :constructor-type="'mapChart'" ref="chart" />

...

let myChart = this.$refs.chart.chart;

myChart.redraw();
```

My hunch is that the drilldown event handlers are also "buried" in the underlying object such that if one wants to connect the wires, one needs to do so at the $refs version of the object and not the Highcharts-Vue level.

As an aside, this may be why various pieces either don't work or don't work as expected: the maps/charts/etc. are all more 'static' in the Highchart-Vue layer. One must do everything upfront like import all the maps rather than load them dynamically. Once mounted() has fired, the component isn't as reactive as the documentation and fiddle examples describe.

All that said, this has nothing to do with Path versus Geometry objects. Hopefully this saves someone some time.